# Celery get task name

Tags: celery

I am using celery in my application, I want to enable or disable some fields in app depending on currently executing task, for this purpose I need the name of the task which is currently in execution.

So, I tried below code but it always returning task name as **None** even though I have specified the task name in the **decorator**.

```
celery_app = Celery(__name__, broker=mc.REDIS_URL, backend=mc.REDIS_URL)
```

```
celery_app.conf.update(
    task_create_missing_queues=True,
    result_extended=True,  # I have enabled this setting but its not working
    worker_prefetch_multiplier=1,
)
```

**Task**

```
@celery_app.task(bind=True, name="job_one")
def background_task_job_one(self, n_clicks):
    status = False
    
    # some long running task

    return status
```

Calling using **apply_async**

```
result: AsyncResult = background_task_job_one.apply_async(args=(some arguments), queue="job_queue")

print(f"Task name: {result.name}")  # expecting job_one but getting None
```

Please suggest.

Comment: I also tried using `celery_app.send_task()` but still getting task name as none. Any other way by which I can get task name? Please suggest.

Comment: Could it be simply that name is set only when task actually got executed? Did you check that task got executed? Also, perhaps you need to call get() first - worth checking...

Comment: Hi DejanLekic, Thanks. Yes, On successful completion, it properly display task name. But I need during execution/running of task. Is it possible? Also a humble request, will you please check this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75114145/celery-and-docker-list-all-tasks-in-all-celery-services) .

Comment: Hi DejanLekic, I have found `inspect()` in celery docs. I am trying to use  `inspect = celery_app.control.inspect()` and then `result = inspect.active()` to get list of running task names.

Comment: active() returns list of tasks that are *currently running*. I fail to see how is that related to what you asked.

Comment: Hi DejanLekic, Yes it returns as you mentioned. Then from that I will extract the `name` key from `hostname: task_info which is a dictiionary`. This way I can get the task names of all currently running tasks.